# Help ID a biplane my Dad flew as a late 1920's barnstormer

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

[image: Martin 70 Commercial with note found in S T Stanton's copy of Lesley Forden's Ford Air Tours 1925-1931][image]My Father flew this ship. Can you help ID it. Photo was taken at the de Havilland Moth Factory
Can't figure out what the heck it is,

- Looks like the tail of a DH-60
- Consolidated PT-1 "N" struts (with strut connecting upper & lower flaps)
- Engine appears to be a Hispano type V-8 (same exhaust on starboard side)
- Upper wing to fuselage connection over passenger seat is really strange
- Never have seen 3 row engine cooling vents like that on any DH model

Comment: Looks like a DH 60 variety. The G-CA registration is Canadian, so it is deHavilland Canada. The last two letters of the registration are not painted on yet. Do you have more information? Did you dad own the aircraft? Was it registered on his name or a company? Do happen to know the registration of the aircraft? Company name, family name?

Comment: The DHC facility on Trethewey Dr was built right around the time the registration CF was adopted so that's likely something from the mid 20s, maybe a one-off of some kind. It doesn't look "DeHavilland-y" at all to me. '

Comment: Little more information, I don't know for sure, but the rear of the lower wing to fuse isn't any DH-60 variant I'm familiar with. The landing gear isn't either, no axle cross strut. Owner (Mr. 'Han'?) I THINK had something to do with late 20's Blackwell Oklahoma's Globe Oil. Unknown registration. Dad, age 29, is S T Stanton.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a 1924 **Martin 70 Commercial** [G-CAVE](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_G-C1.html). It was an unsuccessful aircraft from the [Glenn L. Martin Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenn_L._Martin_Company), only two or three being built. G-CAVE started life as NC2545 (manufacturer serial no.96), one of only two airframes ever registered, and was [exported to Canada](http://www.airhistory.org.uk/gy/reg_N6.html) on 10 June 1928.

Shortly after, your father **S T Stanton** piloted this aircraft with its new owner E V Hemple as passenger, in the [National Air Races of 1928](https://homesteadmuseum.blog/2018/09/15/from-point-a-to-point-b-the-national-air-races-at-mines-field-los-angeles-8-16-september-1928/), from Windsor, Canada to Mines Field, Los Angeles (now LAX):

> William H. E. Drury, youthful pilot of London, Ont., flying a Waco,
> won the international race from Windsor, Canada in 19 hrs., 55 min.,
> 41 sec., averaging 107.63 miles per hour. The distance was 2,145 miles
> with five controls. Drury won first prize of $5,000, ﹩750 lap prizes,
> a Stetson hat, a watch and two pairs of chaparajos ... S. T. Stanton
> and E. V. Hemple, flying a Martin bi-plane, were forced down by engine
> trouble almost within sight of their destination, at Fontana, forty
> miles from Los Angeles.
> [Popular Aviation November 1928](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hwH0nZujtV0C&lpg=PA14&ots=Dx8VglmJ-v&dq=%22E%20V%20Hemple%22%20ontario&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Aviation Week](https://archive.org/details/Aviation_Week_1928-09-22/page/n11/mode/2up) reports:

> S. T. Stanton's Martin was forced down at Fontana, almost with
> striking distance of the finish of the race by engine trouble an hour
> or so after Drury had completed the course. Had he arrived by 5
> o'clock that afternoon he would have won the third prize of $1,500. E.
> V. Hemple, owner of the plane, was with Stanton as a passenger.

Here it the plane before export -

[image: Martin 70 Commercial]
*Martin 70 Commercial, with extended exhaust pipe. This is the same aircraft as in your photo.* [source](https://www.shu-aero.com/AeroPhotos_Shu_Aero/Aircraft_M/Martin/Martin_70_2544_01.html)

[image: Martin 70 Commercial]

*Martin 70 newly manufactured in 1924. The photo shows the luggage / passenger area (forward of the pilot's cockpit) faired over.*

[image: Martin 70 Commercial]
*Martin 70 Commercial, unknown date*

The 70's antecedent was the Martin 66 "Night Mail", which was even less successful - only one was built. As well as the 70, the subsequent Martin N2M-1 (another design that didn't go into production) was also derived from the 66, all sharing the distinctive ogee front-end sweep of the vertical stabilizer.

It is reported "several" 70s were built, but only two airframes were ever registered. There is a little bit more about the aircraft [here](https://dmairfield.org/airplanes/NC2544/index.htm), but it is a bit confused, starting out with your aircraft (96) before jumping to the other airframe (94 / NC2544). I've included a page from [Flight Magazine](https://archive.org/details/Flight_International_Magazine_1924-10-23-pdf/page/n5/mode/2up).

[image: Martin Model 70]

G-CAVE is the only G-CA registration that matches your aircraft.

[image: Martin 70 Commercial]
*Original photo, showing the addition of an extra exhaust pipe to vent behind the pilot.*

Comment: Amazing detail you uncovered. Thank you very much